# Typescript refine string to enum key

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to get TS to refine a string to an enum key without re-casting it?

```
enum SupportedShapes {
  circle = 'circle',
  triangle = 'triangle',
  square = 'square',
}

declare const square: string;

if (square in SupportedShapes) { // Any way to make this check refine `square`?
    SupportedShapes[square];     // Err.  "square as SupportedShapes" works here, but trying to avoid that
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAymAO8D2AnALsAJjAFgQ3mAGcoBvAKCigGMBLFagG2CgF4oByOh5jgGkpQ0KWnhABzZm07DRE3gKpEAjmDwoW7DirUb+5AL7lymYE3UtqSEETRQdFgFz3ZEgNzHaAMygAKBxpQtCCwCMjoWLgExACUZIJUcIioGNj4hEQA2gHAALqGQA)

Comment: Enums have a fixed set of members. The type of an enum's key is `keyof typeof E` but the code itself doesn't make sense because the key will always be present unless you bypass the type checker and mutate the enum. But if you do that you shouldn't use one in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to achieve this.

It consists in declaring a function that returns a `boolean`. This boolean expresses the result of the `key is SupportedShapes` expression and you are responsible of writing the implementation:

```
enum SupportedShapes {
  circle = 'circle',
  triangle = 'triangle',
  square = 'square',
}

declare const square: string;

if (isKeyOfSupportedShapes(square)) {
    SupportedShapes[square];
}

function isKeyOfSupportedShapes(key: string): key is SupportedShapes {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(SupportedShapes, key);
}
```

Comment: I'm not picky person, and your solution is good. You have my upvote, but it might be a bit safer to use `Object.hasOwn` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` instead of `in` operator. https://tsplay.dev/WYBYxw

Comment: Yes indeed it's safer, thanks for pointing out